# Spoon & Espresso - Build Successful. Thats it?

Tags: android, android-testing, spoon, android-espresso

I run my [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide) test via [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/). Often, I get a `build successful`, with tests not being executed. I assume the cause is there was no alterations to the code of the app in question. I can see why they would do this - Why test an app that just ran the same test and passed? However, my situation is different; testing the *app* is not my primary concern, but testing what the app controls.

**My question:** My test will be run on a continuous loop, and the app will not be altered or changed. So is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spoon, a test will not run twice if the first test passed. This is cause it believes if it runs the test again, it will pass and there is no reason for that. Bad design on Square's part if you ask me.

**The solution** is: `gradle clean spoon`. `clean` will regenerate the `res` files (among others) and make spoon believe that it is essentially a different test. This makes running tests take longer than it should. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the cause is there was no alterations to the code of the app
>   in question.

This is not true. You can run the same test thousands of times with Espresso without changing a line of code.

Make sure you're running it the correct way:

```
java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    --apk example-app.apk \
    --test-apk example-tests.apk
```

Also keep in mind that the devices running the test should be visible in adb (run `adb devices` to check).

Comment: You haven't taken the spoon test suite in to consideration.